# Run batch file or command in wix installer when IT disables Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, wix, command-prompt

I've created an installer using wix toolset. Since the main application is a web application, I need to install the web certificate and edit the host file. To do so, I wrote a batch file that will edit the host file and added a Wix property to add the WebCert.

The batch file is as so:

```
FIND /C /I "site.site.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  (
    ECHO. >>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    ECHO ^127.0.0.1 site.site.com>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    ECHO. >>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And in the Component.wxs:

```
<iis:Certificate Id="rootWebCert"
                 Name="site"
                 Request="no"
                 BinaryKey="site.pfx"
                 StoreName="root"
                 PFXPassword="PASSWORD"
                 StoreLocation="localMachine"/>
```

Now this runs fine on computers with more freedom, but there are some computers on our domain that are locked down and one of the features they lock is Command Prompt. Is there an alternative way to edit the host file or install the web cert? I've also done this in PowerShell, but that would require to install PowerShell on the limited computers also.

EDIT:

I was given access to their machines and confirmed that after accepting the EULA and Install Location, the 'Install' button did prompt for elevated permissions and they were able to authenticate through and the installer DID NOT report any errors but the script DID NOT go through. What I found DID work was opening command prompt as admin, and running `msiexec /i installer.msi`

I also added the following lines in the wxs:

```
<Condition Message="Installation requires Administrator privileges">
  <![CDATA[Privileged]]>
</Condition>
```

This part was already there, just forgot to put into the original post:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomBatchFile" After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="CustomBatchFile"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[SHORTCUTDIR]CustomBatch.bat&quot; &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]&quot;"
              Directory="SHORTCUTDIR" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Return="asyncNoWait"/>
```

Comment: 1) It is pointless to block cmd.exe. (cmd.exe is a program, not a security boundary.) You can tell your admins this. 2) If you have Windows Server 2008 R2 or newer, you don't have to "install" PowerShell, as PowerShell is part of the OS.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart wish I could with part 1, they outsource the main IT and we only have help desk guys on site. And that comes with a lot of red tape. Part 2, I forgot the clarify, the nuget package I use with wix (PowerShellWixExtension) requires 3 and higher and some machines I use to test are Windows 7 barebones.

Comment: To clarify: Windows 7, being the client version of Windows Server 2008 R2, comes with PowerShell pre-installed.

Comment: Why not just write a custom action in C/C++ or C#?

Comment: These locked down machines will let you run an elevated installer but they won't let you run cmd.exe?  Or is the problem that they just won't let you run your installer elevated, so your script fails?  They are running Win7 on "locked-down" computers?  For security reasons, Win7 should have been sunsetted long ago.

Comment: are you able to give more details about how it's ***disabled***? Applocker? You can bypass it with [dll/sct](https://github.com/api0cradle/UltimateAppLockerByPassList/blob/master/yml/regsvr32.exe.yml) injection, but I doubt it's even necessary (or legal) to do that...

Comment: @jwdonahue I was able to finally remote in while they installed it. The installer will go through the EULA part then once it gets to the Install button, it will prompt for elevated permissions and confirmed the user authenticated through, and still failed. The only thing that seemed to work was open CMD as admin, then run 'msiexec /i' on the installer

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 it was originally blocked through Group Policy but somewhere along the lines was either disabled or they were given new accounts (company went through a merger). But as my comment above, we were able to open CMD as admin and only successfully run the installer with the msiexec command